# Don't show irrelevant review queue counts/links

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

[image: The problem]

The highlighted 34 in the top right of the above image is referring to the number of items in the Suggested Edits review queue (it also links to that queue). As you can see, I'm currently sitting on that same queue but cannot do anything because I've already completed 20 edits. So the number and the link aren't helpful and in fact, are giving me the impression I can review something that I cannot.

Would it be possible to change this number to refer to - and link to - a queue that I haven't currently exhausted? Preferably the one with the most items, *cough* Close Votes.